# Multiple value insertion in json from two different lists using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists from these two lists i have to place values in multiple rows
**data** is json file in which these values need to be placed
listA = [A,B,C,D]
listB = [11,12,13,14]

Result I would like to see as in json file as

```
"A" : [{
section = 11
}],
"B" : [{
section = 12
}]'
"C" : [{
section = 13
}]
"D" : [{
section = 14
}]
```

but currently i am getting as below

```
"A" : [{
section = 14
}],
"B" : [{
section = 14
}]'
"C" : [{
section = 14
}]
"D" : [{
section = 14
}]
```

The code i am using is below,here data is main json file where i need to place value

```
for j in listA:
  for k in listB:
       if j == 'A' :
            data[j][0]["section"] =  str(k)

       elif j == 'B':
             data[j][0]["section"] =  str(k)

       elif j == 'C' :
            data[j][0]["section"] =  str(k)
       elif j == 'D' :
            data[j][0]["section"] =  str(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well. If you have `data` in this format:

```py
data = {
    "A": [{"section": ""}],
    "B": [{"section": ""}],
    "C": [{"section": ""}],
    "D": [{"section": ""}],
}
```

Then you can use `zip()` to iterate over `listA` and `listB` simultaneously:

```
listA = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
listB = [11, 12, 13, 14]

for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
    data[a][0]["section"] = b

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "A": [{"section": 11}],
    "B": [{"section": 12}],
    "C": [{"section": 13}],
    "D": [{"section": 14}],
}
```